# How to interpolate an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9

I would like to do something like `join` with an `Array`, but instead of getting the result as a `String`, I would like to get an `Array`. I will call this `interpolate`. For example, given:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I expect:

```
a.interpolate(0) # => [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]  
a.interpolate{Array.new} # => [1, [], 2, [], 3, [], 4, [], 5]
```

What is the best way to get this? The reason I need it to take a block is because when I use it with a block, I want different instances for each interpolator that comes in between.

---

After getting great answers from many, I came up with some modified ones.

This one is a modification from tokland's answer. I made it accept `nil` for `conj1`. And also moved `if conj2` condition to outside of the `flat_map` loop to make it faster.

```
class Array
    def interpolate conj1 = nil, &conj2
        return [] if empty?
        if conj2 then first(length - 1).flat_map{|e| [e, conj2.call]}
        else          first(length - 1).flat_map{|e| [e, conj1]}
        end << last
    end
end
```

This one is a modification of Victor Moroz's answer. I added the functionality to accept a block.

```
class Array
    def interpolate conj1 = nil, &conj2
        return [] if empty?
        first, *rest = self
        if conj2 then rest.inject([first]) {|a, e| a.push(conj2.call, e)}
        else          rest.inject([first]) {|a, e| a.push(conj1, e)}
        end
    end
end
```

After benchmark test, the second one looks faster. It seems that `flat_map`, although looking beautiful, is slow.

Comment: Why the block with `Array.new`? can't you just pass that as a parameter?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh Maybe my example was not good, but sometimes, I need different instances for each interpolator.

Comment: That makes sense. That means my answer is worth nothing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to do with a block, but I would do it this way:

```
class Array
  def interpolate(sep)
    h, *t = self
    t.empty? ? [h] : t.inject([h]) { |a, e| a.push(sep, e) }
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Benchmarks (array size = 100):

```
            user     system      total        real
inject  0.730000   0.000000   0.730000 (  0.767565)
zip     1.030000   0.000000   1.030000 (  1.034664)
```

Actually I am a bit surprised, I thought `zip` would be faster.

**UPDATE2:**

`zip` is faster, `flatten` is not.

Comment: I like your idea about `h, *t = self`, but isn't `inject` heavy? I am wondering which is faster between your answer and createing an array and `zipping` it like lucapette's answer.

Comment: It looks like your answer is very fast. Thank you for the benchmark.

Answer (score 6):

Use [zip](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/zip):

```
a.zip(Array.new(a.size) { 0 }).flatten(1)[0...-1]
```

Comment: On my system it yields `[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]]` which is far from desired output :-)

Comment: I guess you forget `.flatten(1)[0...-1]`, besides it creates new array which you don't need in fact

Comment: Your idea looks nice. I am comparing your answer with Victor Moroz's, and wondering which is faster.

Comment: "wondering which is faster", don't wonder, benchmark! But, considering that `zip` is written in C I will go with it as being faster.

Comment: `[0...-1]` I would prefer to see `[0 .. -2]`. The use of `...` is less common and more likely to induce a maintenance problem because it is non-intuitive: `(1..2).to_a
=> [1, 2]` vs. `(1...2).to_a
=> [1]`

Comment: "Which is faster" ... don't worry about it unless you have a large enough data set and observe a problem.  Go with code readability, and if there is a slowdown, use profiling tools and benchmarks to trace the bottleneck.

Comment: @DGM I can't agree more with you.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
class Array
  def interpolate(pol=nil)
    new_ary = self.inject([]) do |memo, orig_item|
      pol = yield if block_given?
      memo += [orig_item, pol]
    end
    new_ary.pop
    new_ary
  end
end

[1,2,3].interpolate("A")
#=> [1, "A", 2, "A", 3]

[1,2,3].interpolate {Array.new}
#=> [1, [], 2, [], 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that your answer is superiour in that it allows `nil` for `pol`. But I am a bit concerned that `inject` might be heavy.

Comment: I did benchmark, and it seems that `+=` is heavy. `inject` is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Array
  def interpolate_with val
    res = []
    self.each_with_index do |el, idx|
      res << val unless idx == 0
      res << el
    end
    res
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :021 > [1,2,3].interpolate_with 0
 => [1, 0, 2, 0, 3] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :022 > [1,2,3].interpolate_with []
 => [1, [], 2, [], 3]
```

Comment: This looks nice. I am comparing this with other answers.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to do this. For example (Ruby 1.9):

```
class Array
  def intersperse(item = nil)
    return clone if self.empty?
    take(self.length - 1).flat_map do |x|
      [x, item || yield]
    end + [self.last]
  end
end

p [].intersperse(0)
#=> []

p [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].intersperse(0)
#= >[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]

p [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].intersperse { 0 }
#= >[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

(I use the Haskell function name: [intersperse](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/Data-List.html#intersperse).)

Comment: Thanks. That is very close to what I wanted.

Comment: I think you can loosen the `return` condition to `if self.empty?`

Comment: @sawa, it is considered bad form to edit someone's answer. You can edit your question to append your version, or you can add a comment to theirs. Editing of answers should be spelling, formatting for readability, etc., but the code should be sacrosanct.

Comment: @sawa: indeed, edited using "empty?". I don't really mind that you edited the question, but the Tin Man is right, it's better to create a separate answer.

Comment: I like the beauty or your code, but after intensive benchmark test, Victor Moroz's answer with modification to allow proc seems to be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version (which can handle multiple values and/or a block) using `flat_map` and `each_cons`:

```
class Array
  def interpolate *values
    each_cons(2).flat_map do |e, _|
      [e, *values, *(block_given? ? yield(e) : [])]
    end << last
  end
end

[1,2,3].interpolate(0, "") # => [1, 0, "", 2, 0, "", 3]
[1,2,3].interpolate(&:even?) # => [1, false, 2, true, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it inplace:

```
class Array
  def interpolate(t = nil)
    each_with_index do |e, i|
      t = yield if block_given?
      insert(i, t) if i % 2 == 1
    end
  end
end
```

This works because `t` is inserted before the element with the current index, which makes the just inserted `t` the element with the current index, which means that the iteration can continue normally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
theArray.map {|element| [element, interpolated_obj]}.flatten
```

Comment: You'll have `interpolated_obj` as the last element of the result and that doesn't look like desired behavior.